# How to get mime type of the file before downloading it?

Tags: firefox-addon, download

It there any way to identify the mime type of file before downloading it (when only url is known)? 
For ex., if I would like to show my context menu item only for some particular types. Or, download screen should be changed depending on the download type.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the MIME type from file extension using `nsIMIMEService.getTypeFromURI()`, it will get the MIME type from the file extension. Along these lines:

```js
var uri = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
                    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService)
                    .newURI("http://example.com/test.gif", null, null);
var mimeService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/mime;1"]
                            .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIMIMEService);
var mime = mimeService.getTypeFromURI(uri);
```

Of course that isn't anything close to reliable - the MIME type of a URL can be anything, `text.gif` can be an HTML page or an SVG image or anything else. So the only real way to get the MIME type is to start the download.

Comment: Thanks, Wladimir. Does FF start to download file prior to showing Download window? The code above is not able to detect mime type, but FF shows it correctly for the link - http://dl.rutracker.org/forum/dl.php?t=3272931.

Comment: Yes, Firefox starts the download first - otherwise it wouldn't even know that it needs to show the download window.

Comment: How to do the same in my extension (to start download to detect mime type and then stop it)? Is there any example to check?

Comment: What if I send HEAD request? Does FF do it?

Comment: @LA_: No, Firefox doesn't do that. Firefox simply starts a download and checks the headers when the first data is received. Either way - this isn't something you would be able to do when the context menu opens, there you would have to rely on the unreliable approach I outlined here (the only one that doesn't require talking to the server).